# Как из одного словаря, скопировать значение в другой словарь, со вложенным словарем?

Tags: python, json, dict

Дано:

- `a_dict` - словарь (14 ключей id), со вложенными словарями, в которых есть пустые значения `value`
- `b_dict` - словарь (12 ключей id), со вложенными словарями, в котором есть заполненные значения `value`

Нужно:
Заполнить `a_dict` значениями из `b_dict` по соответствующим ключам id (id не по порядку и в `a_dict` останутся пустые значения, так как id в нем 14)

Первый словарь:

```
a_dict = {
  "tests": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "S",
    "value": ""
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "D",
    "value": ""
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "P",
    "value": "",
    "values": [{
      "id": 31,
      "title": "M",
      "value": "",
      "values": [ {
        "id": 311,
        "title": "P",
        "values": [{
          "id": 3111,
          "title": "f",
          "value": ""
        }, {
          "id": 3112,
          "title": "f",
          "value": ""
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 32,
      "title": "S",
      "value": "",
      "values": [ {
        "id": 321,
        "title": "P",
        "values": [{
          "id": 3211,
          "title": "s",
          "value": ""
        }, {
          "id": 3212,
          "title": "h",
          "value": ""
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "S",
    "value": "",
    "values": [{
      "id": 41,
      "title": "C",
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": 42,
      "title": "I",
      "value": ""
    }]
  }]
}
```

Второй словарь:

```
b_dict = {
  "values": [{
    "id": 42,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 31,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "failed"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "failed"
  }, {
    "id": 311,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 3111,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 3212,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 41,
    "value": "failed"
  }, {
    "id": 3211,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 321,
    "value": "failed"
  }]
}
```

Перечитал много про вложенные словари, но в итоге даже не могу даже распечатать вложенные словари через цикл из a_dict, чтобы заменить `value`.

```
for t in a_dict["tests"]:
    print(("{} "*len(t)).format(t.get('id'), t.get("value"), t.get('title'), t.get('values')))
```

Подскажите в какую сторону копать. Ощущение, что я что-то упускаю, и будет в итоге что-то типа:

```
for i in range(len(b_dict['values'])):
    if a_dict[id] == b_dict[id]:
         a_dict['tests'][i]['value'] = b_dict['values'][i]['value']
```

Только так меняется только одно значение, а как добраться до остальных `value` в `a_dict`, если они так неравномерно вложены?

`id` в `a_dict` перебором находятся так:

```
print(a_dict["tests"][0]['id'])  # 2
print(a_dict["tests"][1]['id'])  # 41
print(a_dict["tests"][2]['id'])  # 73
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][0]['id'])  # 345
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][0]["values"][0]['id'])  # 230
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][0]["values"][0]["values"][0]['id'])  # 234
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][0]["values"][0]["values"][1]['id'])  # 653
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][1]['id'])  # 110
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][1]["values"][0]['id'])  # 261
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][1]["values"][0]["values"][0]['id'])  # 238
print(a_dict["tests"][2]["values"][1]["values"][0]["values"][1]['id'])  # 690
print(a_dict["tests"][3]['id'])  # 122
print(a_dict["tests"][3]["values"][0]['id'])  # 5321
print(a_dict["tests"][3]["values"][1]['id'])  # 5322
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться рекурсивной функцией:

```
def set_value(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    if d.get("value"):
        return d
    r = [x.get("value") for x in b_dict["values"] if x.get("id") == d.get("id")]
    if r and r[0]:
        d["value"] = r[0]
    return d

def apply_recursive(func, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [apply_recursive(func, elem) for elem in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        obj = func(obj)
        return {k: apply_recursive(func, v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    else:
        return func(obj)
```

вызов:

```
_ = apply_recursive(set_value, a_dict)
```

результат:

```
In [106]: a_dict
Out[106]:
{'tests': [{'id': 1, 'title': 'S', 'value': 'passed'},
  {'id': 2, 'title': 'D', 'value': 'failed'},
  {'id': 3,
   'title': 'P',
   'value': 'failed',
   'values': [{'id': 31,
     'title': 'M',
     'value': 'passed',
     'values': [{'id': 311,
       'title': 'P',
       'values': [{'id': 3111, 'title': 'f', 'value': 'passed'},
        {'id': 3112, 'title': 'f', 'value': ''}],
       'value': 'passed'}]},
    {'id': 32,
     'title': 'S',
     'value': '',
     'values': [{'id': 321,
       'title': 'P',
       'values': [{'id': 3211, 'title': 's', 'value': 'passed'},
        {'id': 3212, 'title': 'h', 'value': 'passed'}],
       'value': 'failed'}]}]},
  {'id': 4,
   'title': 'S',
   'value': 'passed',
   'values': [{'id': 41, 'title': 'C', 'value': 'failed'},
    {'id': 42, 'title': 'I', 'value': 'passed'}]}]}
```

Comment: Макс, спасибо за ответ, но 30 раз перепроверял.. и у меня получается, так же пустые ячейки..

`[{'id': 1, 'title': 'S', 'value': ''},
 {'id': 2, 'title': 'D', 'value': ''},
 {'id': 3,
  'title': 'P',
  'value': '',
  'values': [{'id': 31,
    'title': 'M',
    'value': '',
    'values': [{'id': 311,
      'title': 'P',
      'values': [{'id': 3111, 'title': 'f', 'value': ''},
       {'id': 3112, 'title': 'f', 'value': ''}]}]},
   {'id': 32,
    'title': 'S',
    'value': '',
    'values': [{'id': 321,
      'title': 'P',
      'values': [{'id' (...)`

Comment: @kasius, да, похоже я впоследствии слегка "оптимизировал" функцию `apply_recursive()` ;) Сейчас все должно правильно отрабатывать...

Comment: Все отлично спасибо!!!